# Most efficient way of certain string manipulation in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I have strings that need converting like so,

```
'hello world' = 'helloWorld'
```

And also the same in reverse,

```
'helloWorld' = 'hello world'
```

So far all I have for both the conversions is this for the first,

```
$str = 'hello world';
$str = lcfirst(str_replace(' ', '', ucwords($str))); // helloWorld
```

And the second,

```
$str = 'helloWorld';
$str = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $str);
$str = strtolower(implode(' ', $str)); // hello world
```

Can this not be achieved any easier or any more efficient?

Comment: what's inefficient about that? looks fine to me

Comment: The most efficient way is whichever is the most readable, without fail. Do not make your code an eye-sore for the sake of 0.04ms per request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your camelize code is already good. For the second, you could forgo the split and implode:

```
$str = 'helloWorld';
$str = strtolower(preg_replace('/(?<=\\w)([A-Z])/', ' \\1', $str));
echo $str;
// output: hello world
```

Comment: Thanks will try this, I tried using `preg_replace` before but couldn't get it right.

Comment: This worked great! Could you tell me what `' \\1'` that bit means please or a link so I could find out?

Comment: It's a [back reference](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php). It tells regex to take the text that it found in the original string and "paste" it back here.

Comment: Thank you this is better than what I was using.